# Apache loads forever even if the PHP file is removed

Tags: php, apache, lamp, mod-php

We have a website that, in a certain set of circumstances, crashes and the page is blank and loads forever.

What I don't understand is that once that crash has happened I can close the browser, physically remove index.php from the file system, then point a new browser session (in a different browser) at that URL, and it still loads forever instead of giving a 404 error.

There's no access or error log entries, nothing in dmesg, etc.

The weird thing is, even restarting Apache doesn't fix the issue, so it doesn't appear that it's an Apache process that's locking things up.

I wondered if anybody has experienced anything like this, and knows what the cause could be?

Comment: Could be many things but if restarting Apache doesn't reset things then it could be a completely different process hanging. Can you share the relevant PHP code that causes the crash? Also, please give us more information about the environment and the context in which the code is running.

Comment: What is in your 404 file if you have one?

Comment: most likely either you're missing an actual 404 page / haven't config'd for it to do anything if it can't find the page, or you haven't set a timeout, or both.

Comment: It's actually a Magento 2 installation. If cache files end up with root ownership and can't be overwritten, the site hangs, and then subsequent accesses to the site (even if we remove index.php) also hang. And yes, we have the 404 page configured.